# Steps to resolve the imports in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

Firstly, I have seen several question related to this issue but it seems like those questions might be some steps ahead of my understanding.

I am fairly new to java and consider myself as a self learning beginner. Mostly I face this problem where I do an **import**. I need it because that import is linked with the use of some really nice and powerful function(s), but always fail if import does not work and end up not using that.

The message is, e.g. "The import com.google can not be resolved".

I have been using eclipse in Ubuntu.

After trying some of the given solutions without being able to view them in the proper context, I already have messed up my eclipse environment and the trouble is still there.

Can anybody kindly show me the complete steps of doing these **imports** successfully  in eclipse for java?

Comment: At any given time in eclipse press `Ctrl-Shift-O` (that's a capital O, not a zero) and all your imports will be done automatically. If the import is a resource which isn't built into java, you will need to download the .jar file of that resource and add it to your build path.

Comment: No it did not work so far. Could you kindly tell me the complete steps so that one example error can be removed `The import com.google can not be resolved`? Is this the one about you said `a resource which isn't built into java`? If yes, then what are the steps to do that?

Comment: Find the file on the internet, download it, add it to your build path. Eclipse can't use files that your computer doesn't have.

Comment: If I google "com.google.common.collect.ObjectArrays java", it takes me to the [link](https://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ObjectArrays.html). where and what to download?

Answer (score 0):

For using 3rd party jars you need to add the jars in the build path.

Follow the following step

1. right click project
2. click build path
3. click libraries tab
4. then add external jar

Now give the path of the jar location

Comment: there is not libraries tab, there is an Add libraries... tab but that looks different? what is jars location?

Comment: @tod First you have to download that jar file and give the location

Comment: please, could you kindly give me steps for only one example? i already have messed up? it would be nice if it contains snaps...

Comment: @tod Send me your eclipse screenshot and I will guide you how to do

Comment: @tod How can I show you if you do not provide me the screenshot